# SQL: Generalizing a query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following SQL query,which calculates the avg score for the top **100** entries of the project with the id **1800**. I want to generalize it to calculate the avg score of top **100** entries of every project, so if there are 10 projects the amount of records that would be processed would be 1000, each 100 of those corresponding to a different project_id. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
  SELECT 
    score1.project_id, AVG(score1.final_score)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        project_id, final_score
    FROM
        consultant_project_score
    WHERE
        project_id = 1800
    ORDER BY final_score DESC
    LIMIT 100) score1;
```

Comment: Let's pretend you want the top 3 entries, and you want to generalize it to the top 3 entries of, say, 4 projects. Could you provide proper CREATE and INSERT queries for that, TOGETHER with the desired result.

Comment: well I cannot use create/ insert statements

Comment: Interesting answer. Good luck, then.

Answer (score 0):

Put you logic of calculating average in function and call it in select query against the table.

```
select project_id,calaverage(project_id) as `average`
from
consultant_project_score
```

The function for average can be created as follows:

```
CREATE 
    FUNCTION `calaverage`(projectid INT)
    RETURNS FLOAT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE average FLOAT;
    SELECT 
    AVG(score1.final_score) INTO average
    FROM
    (SELECT 
        project_id, final_score
    FROM
        consultant_project_score
    WHERE
        project_id = projectid
    ORDER BY final_score DESC
    LIMIT 100) score1;
    RETURN average;
    END
```